# How to nest multiple ids in a state url?

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to have a state that I can cold navigate to and not lose the structure of a breadcrumb trail. Ideally the url would look something like this:

site.com/stuff/id1/id2/id3/id4/id5

where ids 1-5 end up in one stateParam.

I have to support a potentially infinite depth. Attempts to regex match with {path: .*} have failed. When I try to navigate I get what looks like a sanitized url ( 84070/84057/84604 becomes 84070%252F84057%252F84604).

A minimal example plunk can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JYRTPZ?p=preview). Be sure to checkout the full screen to see how the URL gets mangled.

pnlkr code:

```
    angular.module('inifinteRoutePrototype', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('stuff', {
        url: '/stuff/{path: *.}',
        templateUrl: 'ids.html',
        controller: 'idsCtrl'
      });
  })
  .run(function($state){
    $state.go('stuff'); //Default to the zipcode form state
  })


  // The controller for the zipcode form
  .controller('idsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams){

    function cleanupUrl(){
      return $stateParams.path.split('/');
    }

    $scope.ids='84070/84057/84604';
    var id = '80000';
    console.log($stateParams.path);

    $scope.go = function(){
      console.log('Attempting navigtation: ' + $state.href('stuff', {path: $scope.ids}));
      $state.go('stuff', {path: $scope.ids});
    };

    $scope.path = cleanupUrl();
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;


  });
```

Comment: is cleanupURL the function that needs to be modified? I'm only somewhat familiar with angular, but I use regular expressions pretty constantly, so if you can provide a little context, I can probably help you.